# Text padding (Gridview) - Material design guidelines

Tags: android, gridview, material-design

Okey, so i'm trying to make a grid of images with a single line of text (material design guidelines). Guidelines for single line:

Single-line header/footer

Height: 48dp

Text padding: 16dp

Default font size: 16sp

The way i did this it makes the text cut off, which kind of makes sense given the text of 16 and the combined padding being 32:

[image: grid]

I used android:padding = 16dp, but i might have misunderstood the guidelines. Could someone help clarify. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.project.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#40000000"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Provide the layout please.

Comment: I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The text is cropped, because there is not enough space for it, because padding is making the actual view smaller.

I end up setting just top and left padding, which means, there is **no bottom padding**. That solved my issue.

```
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
```